# Some boxplot improvements

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have one problem which I'm not able to solve. Let's say I have the code following :

```
x<-rnorm(100)
x<-append(x,5)
ggplot()+geom_boxplot(aes(y=x),width=3)+scale_y_continuous(breaks=round(c(median(x),summary(x)[['1st Qu.']],summary(x)[['3rd Qu.']],max(x),min(x)),digits=2))
```

[image]

As you can see above, that boxplot is huge! How can I change it's width ? As you can see above, I tried to do it by command `width` but it didn't work (which is very strange to me, because I read some posts about that and the `width` command was working.

The second thing I want to do is to mark values which are relevant to boxplot (as median, 1st quantile, 3rd quantile, max,min) but I want to have always top of the stick marked (`max()` for instance will mark outlier if exist).
As you can see above, outlier is marked by `max()` function, but top of the upper stick is not marked. Is there any way how can we do it ? I tried to do it by adding to `breaks=()` command :

```
 ifelse(max(x)>(3/2*summary(x)[['3rd Qu.']]),max(x[x<3/2*summary(x)[['3rd Qu.']]]),"")
```

But it's not working. My intuition was : If outlier exist (condition) then mark top of the stick which is the nearest value to 3/2* 3rd quantile. Is there any way how can we solve those two issues ?

Comment: How are you exporting the plot from R?

Comment: Export -> Save as image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
set.seed(123)

x <- rnorm(100)
x <- append(x,5)

my_breaks <- summary(x)[-4] %>% as.numeric()
my_range <- my_breaks[c(2,4)] + (my_breaks[c(2,4)] %>% diff() * 3/2) * c(-1, 1)
my_breaks <- c(my_breaks, x[x >= my_range[1] & x <= my_range[2]] %>% range())

data <- data.frame(group = factor(0), y = x)

ggplot(data)+
  geom_boxplot(aes(group, y), width = 0.25) +
  labs(x = NULL) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = round(my_breaks, 2)) +
  theme(
    axis.title.x=element_blank(),
    axis.text.x=element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x=element_blank()
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks ;)) At the begging we also have to use library(dplyr) ;))